# when I add a component of select to the render(), then i have two select instead of one select having multiple options

Tags: reactjs

I am adding a select component like code below. After adding an author, i have two authors in the array, but I am having two select with the code below. Sorry for being stupid first I just started learning React.

```
let authorNames = this.state.authors.map((author, index) => {

            return (
                <select
                    onChange={e => {
                        let { newBookData } = this.state;
                        newBookData.author_id = e.target.value;
                        this.setState({ newBookData });
                    }}
                    key={author.id}
                    className="form-control"
                >
                    <option>Select an author ...</option>
                    <option key={author.id} value={author.id}>
                        {this.getAuthorName(author.id)}
                    </option>
                </select>
            );
        });
```

and I add like this..

```
render(){
    {authorNames}
}
```

then I have the view like this, having two selects. What i have done wrong?

[You can see the result image from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFYlo.png)

Comment: may be your map has two entries?

Comment: Well.. you are mapping each entry of `authors` to be a select element (see your return function). If you have two authors, that's two selects.

Comment: @entiendoNull I can see now. if I have three authors, I would have three selects. thinking how to fix it.

Comment: Why are you mapping each `author` to a select with only 1 real option to select from? Map the `authors` to the options inside a single `select`.

Comment: @DrewReese i am working on it. Firstly, the reason why i put outside select is to send 'author_id' when I select. I just started learning ReactJs and need some examples to understand. I probably research more.

Comment: Great! Keep on working on it and update question if you get stuck. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you want to build is a `select` input that has all the authors in the `this.state.authors` array as options. For that, this would be how I go about it.

```
let selectAuthorOptions = this.state.authors.map((author, index) => {
  return (<option key={author.id} value={author.id}>
    {this.getAuthorName(author.id)}
  </option>)
})

selectAuthorOptions = [(<option key="default">Select an author ...</option>)].concat(selectAuthorOptions)

let selectAuthor = (<select onChange={e => {
                        let { newBookData } = this.state;
                        newBookData.author_id = e.target.value;
                        this.setState({ newBookData });
                    }}
                    className="form-control">
  {selectAuthorOptions}
</select>
```

Comment: I feel like you have used components really well to combine those.

Comment: Ah didn't notice the author.id, its not needed in the select. Also added the key to the default option.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to render just 1 `select` then use the `.map` to create the options you want.

```
render(){
    <select
        onChange={e => {
            let { newBookData } = this.state;
            newBookData.author_id = e.target.value;
            this.setState({ newBookData });
        }}
        key={author.id}
        className="form-control"
    >
        <option>Select an author ...</option>
        {this.state.authors.map((author, index) => {
            <option key={author.id} value={author.id}>
                {this.getAuthorName(author.id)}
            </option>
        })

    </select>
}
```

Comment: how do I deal with select onChage? I put Onchange in select to send author_id when I make a new book.